# How to show the input integer in reversed in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: vb6, reverse

Good day! I have a problem in Visual Basic 6.0.

I created two `textbox`s, 1 for input and one for output.

The output should be the reverse of the input.

Example :

Input : 345
Output : 543

This is what I've coded so far.

```
Dim rev, n As Integer
rev = Val(Text1.Text)
rev = rev * 10
rev = rev + n Mod 10
n = n / 10
Text2.Text = n
```

Whenever I click the command button, it just returns 0 no matter what value entered in my input.

Comment: Why don't you reverse it as a string? `StrReverse`

Comment: ^I don't know how to do that. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
Text2.Text = StrReverse(Text1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

n is never assigned anything but `0` in your code (and divided by 10)

[Use StrReverse to reverse a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e462ax87%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
Dim TestString As String = "ABCDEFG" 
' Returns "GFEDCBA". 
Dim revString As String = StrReverse(TestString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Dim rev, n As Integer
>   rev = Val(StrReverse(Text1.Text))
>   Text2.Text = rev

Comment: Why use val, it doesn't add anything?

Comment: Yes. you are right. Can omit the val unless you want to perform some sort of calculation before that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe than you are using number and since numbers can be in negative thus StrReverse Function would not help much as it Reverse the String i.e. the Positive Numbers only. You have to create function as:

```
Dim num As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim f As Integer

s = 0           '~~~ The result(reversed number) will be stored in this variable

num = -123      '~~~ Number to be reversed

'~~~ Checking whether it is negative or not
If num < 0 Then
    num = Abs(num)  '~~~ If negative, take it's absolute value, positive value
    f = -1          '~~~ Keep a flag that it is a negative number
Else
    f = 1           '~~~ For positive number
End If

'~~~ Reverse the number
Do While num > 0
    n = num Mod 10
    s = s * 10 + n
    num = num / 10
Loop
s = s * f   '~~~ Getting back the sign

MsgBox s    '~~~ Display it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim r_m As Integer
    Dim d_v As Integer
    Dim rev As Integer
    rev = 0
    d_v = Text1.Text
    While (d_v >= 1)
      r_m = d_v Mod 10
       rev = rev * 10 + r_m
       d_v = d_v / 10
    Wend
    Text2.Text = rev
    End Sub
```

Comment: This proper code to this above program is what I presented . The above program is  wrong therefore output is zero , . r_m = remainder ,  d_v = dividend and rev = reverse , 10 is always the divisor here

Comment: You should probably add the text and description to the code within the answer, instead of comments for clarity. Might also wanna explain the code, and why this is a fix for this exact question, as to why the original code is not working - After all, we're here to help each other! :)