# Reversing Digits

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a function that takes a three digit number and reverses it (543 into 345)
I can't take that value from a TextBox because I need it to use the three numbers trick to find a value.

```vb
RVal = ReverseDigits(Val)
Diff = Val - RVal
RDiff = ReverseDigits(Diff)
OVal = Diff + RDiff
```

543-345=198
198+891=1089

Then it puts 1089 in a TextBox

```vb
Function ReverseDigits(ByVal Value As Integer) As Integer
    ' Take input as abc
    ' Output is (c * 100 + b * 10 + a) = cba
    Dim ReturnValue As Boolean = True
    Dim Val As String = CStr(InputTextBox.Text)
    Dim a As Char = Val(0)
    Dim b As Char = Val(1)
    Dim c As Char = Val(2)

    Value = (c * 100) + (b * 10) + (a)

    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

I've tried this but can't figure out why it won't work.

Comment: I don't know visual basic (try to avoid it at all costs, tbh) but it seems like your `ReturnValue` is a boolean (True/False) rather than the `Value` you calculate. Try returning `Value` instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show the input integer in reversed in Visual Basic 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434472/how-to-show-the-input-integer-in-reversed-in-visual-basic-6-0)

Comment: @GabrielDevillers if this was VB6, sure.

Comment: What about _(taking your example value)_ `Val(Strings.StrReverse((543).ToString))`?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the integer to a string, reverse the string, then convert back to an integer. You may want to enforce the three digit requirement. You can validate the argument before attempting conversion

```vb
Public Function ReverseDigits(value As Integer) As Integer
    If Not (value > 99 AndAlso value < 1000) Then Throw New ArgumentException("value")
    Return Integer.Parse(New String(value.ToString().Reverse().ToArray()))
End Function
```

My code is pretty simple and will also work for numbers that don't have three digits assuming you remove that validation. To see what's wrong with your code, there are a couple of things. See the commented lines which I changed. The main issue is using `Val` as a variable name, then trying to index the string like `Val(0)`. `Val` is a built in function to vb.net and the compiler may interpret `Val(0)` as a function instead of indexing a string.

```vb
Function ReverseDigits(ByVal Value As Integer) As Integer
    ' Dim ReturnValue As Boolean = True
    ' Dim Val As String = CStr(InputTextBox.Text)
    Dim s As String = CStr(Value)
    Dim a As Char = s(0)
    Dim b As Char = s(1)
    Dim c As Char = s(2)

    Value = Val(c) * 100 + Val(b) * 10 + Val(a)

    'Return ReturnValue
    Return Value
End Function
```

(Or the reduced version of your function, but I would still not hard-code the indices because it's limiting your function from expanding to more or less than 3 digits)

```vb
Public Function ReverseDigits(Value As Integer) As Integer
    Dim s = CStr(Value)
    Return 100 * Val(s(2)) + 10 * Val(s(1)) + Val(s(0))
End Function
```

And you could call the function like this

```vb
Dim inputString = InputTextBox.Text
Dim inputNumber = Integer.Parse(inputString)
Dim reversedNumber = ReverseDigits(inputNumber)
```

Bonus: If you really want to use use math to find the reversed number, here is a version which works for any number of digits

```vb
Public Function ReverseDigits(value As Integer) As Integer
    Dim s = CStr(value)
    Dim result As Integer
    For i = 0 To Len(s) - 1
        result += CInt(Val(s(i)) * (10 ^ i))
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: For really *really* using only maths, `Function ReverseDigits(n As Integer) As Integer` `Dim x = 0` `While n > 0` `x *= 10` `x += n Mod 10` `n = n \ 10` `End While` `Return x` `End Function`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I like it. I was building upon OP's method, more or less. There are many ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I wrote recently when someone else posted basically the same question elsewhere, probably doing the same homework:

```vb
Private Function ReverseNumber(input As Integer) As Integer
    Dim output = 0

    Do Until input = 0
        output = output * 10 + input Mod 10
        input = input \ 10
    Loop

    Return output
End Function
```

That will work on a number of any length.